# Python + Mysql : Insert geojson polygon value to mysql sptial column

Tags: python, mysql, geometry, polygon, spatial

I have a geojson file that contains polygon data. below is example of it.

```
[[[127.00733253963132, 37.583203339216226], 
 [127.00884131783923, 37.58045263873488], 
 [127.00861398800201, 37.57670881432089],
 [127.00783306341832, 37.57663511179821], 
 [126.99967765278153, 37.57589728327857], 
 [126.9971834726848, 37.57693224535312], 
 [126.99675796489285, 37.578422160319896], 
 [126.99660663904614, 37.579345394336194], 
 [126.99641172469617, 37.580645880422686], 
 [126.99649978451932, 37.581022567729896], 
 [126.99823026308687, 37.581266540341], 
 [127.00180462191403, 37.58253031283794], 
 [127.00172112834049, 37.583133635452405], 
 [127.00272082947205, 37.583723680505784], 
 [127.00580459526145, 37.584756278282704],
 [127.00618219538146, 37.58396129485959], 
 [127.00733253963132, 37.583203339216226]]]
```

I have spatial table in mysql. I'm trying to insert this polygon data into polygon column using row sql, however, keep failing. Later, I found polygon data that inserted in mysql db looks little bit different from what I have. This is the data that I've seen from internet tutorial.

```
((126.97688884274817 37.575650779448786,  
126.9770344988775 37.569194530054546,  
126.97597472821249 37.569336299425764,   
126.97537470991254 37.569315567021562,   
126.97433193562325 37.569261800517531,  
126.96904837001854 37.568194417708312,  
126.96854493603384 37.568427679612753,  
126.9666499598212 37.569491655206569,  
126.96628175024485 37.569700734798701,  
126.9660973270804 37.569856509723699,  
126.96572852922577 37.570183936115114,   
126.96592699822128 37.570318805686199,   
126.96601094018429 37.57154839557748,   
126.96365922052196 37.575174660660359,   
126.96308600434513 37.576485920015529,   
126.96284099051198 37.576661586092726,   
126.96281041047263 37.579448809656768,  
126.96742431584332 37.579601537124489,   
126.96742176302651 37.579263521441646,   
126.9674300601846 37.579192577998612,   
126.96745709009561 37.578975250585444,   
126.96806604699626 37.578246780467865,   
126.96895511695477 37.577935262340283,  
126.96921284296906 37.577935299309395,   
126.96941453886579 37.578121124142172,   
126.96966442669471 37.578531136682209,  
126.96966721914872 37.578736205134923,   
126.96966877353309 37.578992879009881,   
126.96966949910363 37.579112526749597,  
126.96990457361626 37.579301753628719,   
126.97135197544759 37.579513277939817,   
126.97381925784454 37.579372140302631,  
126.97391736338342 37.578487073041011,   
126.97393961998088 37.578240429978088,   
126.97433153835757 37.575749906299862,   
126.97580378997804 37.575649468824203,  
126.97688884274817 37.575650779448786 ))'
```

So the idea that I have is make polygon data into string and just replace the brackets using regex. However this methods will takes lot of time. So, I wonder if there is any solution to insert this data into mysql polygon field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using PostgreSQL and PostGIS, you could use the [GeoAlchemy2](http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library. But I think there is no support for MySQL at this moment, someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I wonder if mysql does not support inserting geojson polygon value to mysql table? or just geoalchemy does not support polygon with mysql